# How do I get the sums for all elements of two lists in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I have two lists:

```
val x: List<Int> = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val y: List<Int> = listOf(2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

How do I get:

```
val z: List<Int> = 3,5,7,9,11,13
```

without using loops?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming both list have **the same size**:

1. Using [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html)

   ```
   val sum = x.zip(y) { xv, yv -> xv + yv }
   ```
2. Using simple `map` and `mapIndexed`

   ```
   val sum = (0 until x.size).map { x[it] + y[it] }
   // or
   val sum = x.mapIndexed { index, xv -> xv + y[index] }
   ```

When the size **can be different** and you would assume 0 for out of range entries:

1. Using an `array`

   ```
   val sum = IntArray(maxOf(x.size, y.size)) { 
       x.getOrElse(it, {0}) + y.getOrElse(it, {0}) 
   }.toList()
   ```
2. Using range:

   ```
   val sum = (0 until maxOf(x.size, y.size)).map { 
       x.getOrElse(it, {0}) + y.getOrElse(it, {0})
   }
   ```
3. Extending the lists to same size

   ```
   val xExtended = x + Array(maxOf(0, y.size - x.size), { 0 })
   val yExtended = y + Array(maxOf(0, x.size - y.size), { 0 })
   val sum = xExtended.zip(yExtended) { xv, yv -> xv + yv }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a range and `map`:

```
val sums = (0 until x.size).map { x[it] + y[it] }
```

It's probably less overhead than `zip`.

Comment: I checked, zip does minimally more work (namely range checks). Therefore I would prefer `zip()`, for safety and readability.

Comment: @leoderprofi So the created intermediate zipped list isn’t relevant

Comment: map(), as well as zip() return a new List therefore both have the same overhead for creating an object. In addition I did a small performance test (nothing worthy of sowing) and concluded that the performance of both is equal.